# Cannot open database "tda" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'tda'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this error when i want to perform an action related to my published database:

> Cannot open database "tda" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'tda'.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
>   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
>   about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database 
>   "tda" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'tda'.

This is my connection string in my Web.Config file

```
 <add name="TupperwareDemAppConnString1" connectionString="Data Source=SICT- 
  SQL;Database=xxx;Integrated Security = false;User ID=tda;Password=xxxxx;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This is my connection string in my code:

```
   String CS =[ ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
   ["TupperwareDemAppConnString1"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Well, it sounds like tda's password isn't actually xxxxx. Have you tried logging into it with that account using something like [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: lol that is just a placeholder.....I have tried and it was successful. @itsme86

Comment: Well, the error says quite clearly that the login failed - so you do get to the server, you just can't pass through the gate - so it's either a problem with the password or a problem with the user name. It's not credentials to the specific database because that would cause a different error message.

Comment: You say you've logged in, but have you logged into the server using the SQL user you have in your connection string?

Comment: your password is incorrect